# Best tutorials of Selenium Python bindings for beginners

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am a beginner in automation field. I want to learn python selenium.
I am finding difficulty in finding the best beginner tutorials through which I can get the best knowledge.

Please refer me the best tutorials for python selenium.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the documentation: [Click here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

This is the most basic and detailed tutorial you will get!

Comment: HI @KEV, Actually i am beginner that's why i am not able to vote up your answer due to my less reputation at this stage.